# Python Eve - Update Record if exists otherwise Insert

Tags: python, mongodb, eve

I'm using the default example..

**run.py**

```
from eve import Eve
app = Eve(template_folder=tmpl_dir)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

**settings.py**

```
RESOURCE_METHODS = ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE']
ITEM_METHODS = ['GET', 'PUT', 'PATCH', 'DELETE']
CACHE_CONTROL = 'max-age=20'
CACHE_EXPIRES = 20

IF_MATCH = False

people = {
    # 'title' tag used in item links.
    'item_title': 'person',
    'item_url': 'regex("[a-zA-Z0-9.]+")',
    'item_lookup': True,
    'item_lookup_field': 'firstname',
    'additional_lookup': {
        'url': 'regex("[\w]+")',
        'field': 'firstname'
    },
    'schema': {
        'firstname': {
            'type': 'string',
            #'required': True,
            'unique': True,
        },
        'age': {
            'type': 'integer'
        }
    }
}

DOMAIN = {
    'people': people
}
```

Now, i can easily create new entries by

```
curl -X POST -F "firstname=john" -F "age=24" "http://127.0.0.1:5000/people"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{"_updated": "Fri, 02 Dec 2016 10:12:58 GMT", "_created": "Fri, 02 Dec 2016 10:12:58 GMT", "_status": "OK", "_id": "5841492a10cf9320678bef65", "_links": {"self": {"href": "people/5841492a10cf9320678bef65", "title": "person"}}}
```

I can now easily send a curl request

```
curl -X GET "http://127.0.0.1:5000/people/john"
```

and get the record since **firstname** is in my additional lookup

**OUTPUT**

```
{"_updated": "Fri, 02 Dec 2016 10:12:58 GMT", "firstname": "john", "age": 24, "_links": {"self": {"href": "people/5841492a10cf9320678bef65", "title": "person"}, "collection": {"href": "people", "title": "people"}, "parent": {"href": "/", "title": "home"}}, "_created": "Fri, 02 Dec 2016 10:12:58 GMT", "_id": "5841492a10cf9320678bef65"}
```

I can now also patch the document and change the age by,

```
curl -X PATCH -F "age=32" "http://127.0.0.1:5000/people/john"
```

**OUTPUT**

```
{"_updated": "Fri, 02 Dec 2016 10:15:56 GMT", "_created": "Fri, 02 Dec 2016 10:12:58 GMT", "_status": "OK", "_id": "5841492a10cf9320678bef65", "_links": {"self": {"href": "people/5841492a10cf9320678bef65", "title": "person"}}}
```

My Question:

The above **PATCH** will only work when the record exists, is there a way i can send a PUT or a PATCH request with the data and let eve decide to either create new entry or modify if the entry already exists?

hope my question is clear enough

Comment: http://python-eve.org/features.html#event-hooks

Comment: UPSERT_ON_PUT functionality already exists but can't seem to be working. what am i missing?

Comment: are you getting same error?: `id = lookup[resource_def['id_field']] 
KeyError: '_id'
`

Comment: my issue is similar to this guys' issue which is already marked solved but I'm still getting the same error https://github.com/nicolaiarocci/eve/issues/803

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The additional endpoint you set up with `additional_lookup` is read-only:

> Besides the standard item endpoint which defaults to `/<resource>/<ID_FIELD_value>`, you can optionally define a secondary, **read-only**, endpoint like `/<resource>/<person_name>`.

In your settings, I think you do not need to set `additional_lookup` at all, as it is just redefining `item_lookup_field`(which sets up your read/write endpoint).

Comment: removing additional_lookup, and sending a PUT request to /<resource>/NEW_ID_FIELD_VALUE with data will create new entry in my collection?

Comment: did a pip install upgrade eve and everything started working as documented  on the website.  basically i was on version 0.5.3 apparently. i wonder why?